# Google Charts Pie chart displaying Other 100%

Tags: php, json

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

          <?php
            $query = "SELECT name, score FROM `Users` order by score desc limit 5";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo "['".$row['name']."', '".$row['score']."'],";
              } 
            }
          ?>

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code? i have read that my values are stored as string so that the chart is showing 100% other.

How do i make it work? i tried with `(int)$var` PHP function, but that does not make it work yet..

```
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                $score = $row['score'];
                $int = (int)$score;
                echo "['".$row['name']."', '".$row['score']."'],";
              } 
            }
```

Comment: Your output is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not** generate json by yourself. Use `json_encode` **always**:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT name, score FROM `Users` order by score desc limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$chartData = [
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $chartData[] = [$row['name'], $row['score']];
    } 
}?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($chartData)?>);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```